# MS excel sheet is not showing properly through ZOHO excel viewer

Tags: php

```
<form method="POST" action="https://sheet.zoho.com/remotedoc.im" target="_self" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

File :

I tried the above and I get a response like below:
RESULT=TRUE
URL=https://sheet.zoho.com/editor.do?doc=c2826da1f9894a549f13cf1172e390a30cabeb061f45f393&lang=en

I want to see it inside a web browser using ZOHO sheet.

Comment: I don't know what is the actual problem is going on.Please give any idea about the problem.

Comment: Without the actual problem people cant help

Comment: try to open that url. it shows you and error. Try to figur out why that happens.

Comment: When I submit the above form then, URL=https://sheet.zoho.com/editor.do?doc=c2826da1f9894a549f13cf1172e390a30cabeb061f45f393&lang=en

Comment: Choose a file 
File : <input type="file" name="content" size="38" value=""> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="a1a00a67760e39e2ecb8b1187d05271b">
and submit the form with this apikey, then showing the above "URL", but if this is run on a browser, then the excel file is not showing properly.

Comment: please give me a solution regards this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="https://sheet.zoho.com/remotedoc.im" target="_self" accept-charset="UTF-8">
File : <input type="file" name="content" size="38" value=""> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="apikey" value="a1a00a67760e39e2ecb8b1187d05271b">
<input type="hidden" name="output" value="url">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="normaledit">
<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="mydocument.doc">
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="22345678">
<input type="hidden" name="format" value="xlsx">
<input type="hidden" name="saveurl" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Open/Edit">
</form>
```

This is the original form.After submit it, I can't view the excel sheet.